# Why is my mocked database query returning an empty result in my Laravel feature test

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

Hi I was trying to implement feature testing but I could not make, here so far what I did.

```
list($payload, $orderId) = $data;

$settingsDirect = [
    (object) [ "id" => "1", "setting" => "mysetting", "param" => "skip_limit", "val" => "1" ],
    (object) [ "id" => "2", "setting" => "mysetting", "param" => "skip_days", "val" => "7" ],
    (object) [ "id" => "3", "setting" => "mysetting", "param" => "retry_limit", "val" => "1" ],
    (object) [ "id" => "4", "setting" => "mysetting", "param" => "kill_switch", "val" => "1" ],
];

DB::shouldReceive('connection')->with('externalconnection')->andReturnSelf();
DB::shouldReceive('table')->with('transactions')->andReturnSelf();
DB::shouldReceive('where')->with('cancelled', false)->andReturnSelf();
DB::shouldReceive('whereIn')->with('transaction_number', [])->andReturnSelf();
DB::shouldReceive('get')->andReturn(collect([]));
DB::shouldReceive('table')->with('settings')->andReturnSelf();
DB::shouldReceive('where')->with('setting', 'mysettings')->andReturnSelf();
DB::shouldReceive('get')->andReturn($settingsDirect);

$response = $this->call(
    'POST',
    'api/some/end/point',
    [],
    [],
    [],
    ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/xml'],
    $payload
);
```

So it will call the endpoint `'api/some/end/point'` and some controller will receive the XML content.
In the receiving method, it will call some object and that object has a `method` for checking if
`$payload` is not an existing transaction.

Like

First connection:

```
$transactions = DB::connection('externalconnection')
    ->table('transactions')
    ->where('cancelled', false)
    ->whereIn('transaction_number', $transactionNumbers)
    ->get();
```

after that it will dispatch to a job (queue job)

and in that job there will be another

Second Connection:

```
$settingsDirect = DB::connection('externalconnection')
    ->table('settings')
    ->where('setting', 'mysetting')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

This one is the `$settingsDirect` is empty

Can anyone tell me what happened, why it's empty and what to do with it?

Comment: Do not mock database queries, just have fake data and expect the right stuff back. Why didn't you tried that?

Comment: I don't know, I am a beginner in this area, any source i can read?

Comment: I am not exactly sure. You should not mock queries because you could have stuff in the background, for example, if you were using a model, you could have global scopes that you're going to ignore if mocking. The idea is to use a fake database (create a database juse for testing) and put anything that you need for that test there. You can read this: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database-testing. Adding fake data to the fake database is going to be more "real" and easier

Comment: I read it, but it's more suitable for main database, the one I am trying is connecting to the database that other application is using

Comment: You can still fake that, just set the `DB_HOST` (of that connection, on the `phpunit.xml`) of that database to be yours and have one for tests. I have done it a lot of times, it is way faster and better testing than mocking connections and queries, you should never have the need to do so